# Nested Loop to add numbers

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested

I am currently trying to create a double nested loop that adds a number to itself, given the number of instances you want it to be added by.

So when you input something in the Number, for example "5" and you input "3" for the number of instances, then the following would be printed:

```
5=5 
5+5=10 
5+5+5=15
```

More information on my [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OutlinedAce/heerf788/)

```
<div>
  <h2>Loop</h2>
  Number
  <input type='text' id='tbox'>
  <br>
  Number of Instances
  <input type='text' id='theNumber'> 

  <button onclick=doubleLoop;>
    Add Numbers.
  </button>
</div>
<div id="content">
</div>

<script>
    function doubleLoop(){
        var theText = document.getElementById('tbox').value;
        var theNumber = document.getElementById('theNumber').value;
        var content = document.getElementById('content');
        content.innerHTML = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < theNumber; i++) {
            content.innerHTML = content.innerHTML + (i + 1) + ')';
            //start of the second part of the Double Loop
            for (var j = 0; j < (i + 1); j++){
                if (i === 0){
                    content.innerHTML = content.innerHTML + theText + '=' + theText + '<br>';
                } else if (i > 0) {
                    content.innerHTML = content.innerHTML + theText.repeat(j) + '=' + (theText * (i+1));
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

First things first: You're naming your variables very poorly, it's really difficult to understand what you're trying to do, specially when you don't say what you want directly in the question. `doubleLoop` says how your function works but not what it does. `getMultiplicationProcess` would have been a better name. Also, you could be passing the values as arguments and just returning the result, it would look A LOT better.

Anyway, I couldn't figure how you were trying to achieve this. I've renamed your variables and did everything my way. Never name a variable `theNumber` or `theText` because doing so says nothing about what information it holds. You could have named them `firstInput` and `secondInput` but even that way it would not be clear.

Here's the code, scroll down for explanation:

```
var submit = document.getElementById("submit"),
    firstInput = document.getElementById("tbox"),
    secondInput = document.getElementById("theNumber"),
    answerField = document.getElementById("content");

submit.addEventListener("click", function () {
    answerField.innerHTML = getMultiplicationProcess(Number(firstInput.value), Number(secondInput.value), "<br/>");
});


function getMultiplicationProcess(multiplicand, multiplier, lineBreak) {
  var result = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < multiplier; ++i) {
    for (var j = 0; j < i + 1; ++j) {
      if (i === j) {
        result += multiplicand + " = " + (multiplicand * (i + 1));
      } else result += multiplicand + " + ";
    }
    result += lineBreak || "\n";
  }
  return result;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/heerf788/8/)

**Explanation:**

The outer `for` loop runs as many times as the second input, or `multiplier`. So if you input `5` and `3` respectively this loop will run three times. It represents each line of the resulting string.

The inner loop runs as many times as the current iteration number of the outer loop more one. So for our example inputs it will run like this:

`0: 1; 1: 2; 2: 3;`

I use it to place the `multiplicand` multiple times in the current line.

The first line will contain a single `5` (not including the answer for this multiplication) so `j` is `i + 1` which is `1` because during the first iteration from the outer loop `i` equals `0`:

`5 = 5`

The second line contains 2 `5`s and `i` is `1` because we're in the second iteration for the outer loop, so `j = i + 1 = 2` which is how many fives we'll place in the string:

`5 + 5 = 10`

if it's the last iteration of the inner loop instead of adding `"5 + "` to the resulting string it places `"5 = (i + 1) * multiplier"` which will be the result for the current line. Then the inner loop ends, the outer loop adds a line break and restarts the process for the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

**https://jsfiddle.net/mkarajohn/qkn2ef4L/**

```
function createString(number, times) {
    /*
   * We will create each side of the equation separately and we will concatenate them at the end
   */
  var leftSide = '', 
      rightSide = '',
      i;

  for (i = 1; i <= times; i++) {
    leftSide += number.toString();
    if ((times > 1) && (i < times)) {
      leftSide += '+';
    }
  }
  rightSide = number * times

  return (leftSide + '=' + rightSide);
}

function loop(){
  // .value returns a string, so we make sure the values are converted to integers by calling parseInt()
  // See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt
  var theText = parseInt(document.getElementById('tbox').value);
  var theNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById('theNumber').value);
  var content = document.getElementById('content');
  var output = '';

  content.innerHTML = '';

  for (var i = 1; i <= theNumber; i++) {
    output += createString(theText, i);
    output += '<br />'
  }

  content.innerHTML = output;
}

var button = document.getElementById('run');
run.addEventListener('click', loop);
```

If there is something that is not clear feel free to ask.

EDIT: If you are hell bent on doing it with two nested loops, here's how it would go:

```
function loop(){
  // .value returns a string, so we make sure the values are converted to integers by calling parseInt()
  // See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt
  var theText = parseInt(document.getElementById('tbox').value);
  var theNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById('theNumber').value);
  var content = document.getElementById('content');
  var output = '';
  var leftSide = '', 
      rightSide = '';

  content.innerHTML = '';

  for (var i = 1; i <= theNumber; i++) {
    leftSide = '';
    for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
      leftSide += theText.toString();
      if ((i > 1) && (j < i)) {
        leftSide += '+';
      }
    }
    rightSide = theText * i;
    output += (leftSide + '=' + rightSide);
    output += '<br />'
  }

  content.innerHTML = output;
}


var button = document.getElementById('run');
run.addEventListener('click', loop);
```